# visual studio 092 on ubuntu c++ code run issue — error message “launch: property 'program' is missing or empty”

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

After running c++ code in Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu I have got next error:

> error message "launch: property 'program' is missing or empty"

i see answer: Your startup project must be a C++ project. Right-click it, then click Properties => Debugging => Working Directory setting. Default is $(ProjectDir) . It sounds like yours is empty; but
i nothing understand, i trying to click properties but here only 3 tabs basic permissions and open with, and nothing about debugging, in visual studio i also trying to see something about this, but only changed plain text on c++ in downbar

Comment: So you run Visual Studio in Ubuntu, do you mean [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)? Or when you say "Visual Studio" do you mean [Integrated Development Environment (a.k.a. an IDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) more generally? Which IDE are you *really* using?

Comment: Also regarding the right clicking and dialogs, you should do this *inside* the IDE, right click on the project in the project tree from inside the program, not in the normal file system.

Comment: it's visual studio code i dont note this differences

Comment: Visual Studio Code is primarily for web-development, it doesn't come with a compiler and doesn't even have IntelliSense enabled for C++. Maybe this non-support for C++ is why you're having problems?

Comment: oh lol i change c++ language in downbar where by default was plain text, text editor also backlighting  c++ syntax